# python freeopcua import error: cannot import name Client

Tags: python, opc-ua

folks, i got python 3.5.0 installed on a windows 7 machine and used pip3 to install dependencies cryptography, dateutil, lxml and pytz as mentioned on the freeopcua homepage. 
thereafter I installed freeopcua using pip3 as well.

when trying to run one of the examples https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/master/examples/client_to_kepware.py I got the error

`1 import sys 
2 sys.path.insert(0, "..") 
3 import logging 
4 
5 from opcua import Client 
6 from opcua import uaprotocol as ua`

**"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx\Desktop\opcua.py", line 5, in 
    from opcua import Client
  File "xxx\Desktop\opcua.py", line 5, in 
    from opcua import Client
ImportError: cannot import name 'Client'"**

in my directory "xxx\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages" I do see opcua and freeopcua-0.09.3-py3.5.egg-info so it appears to be intalled correctly.
inside opcua package there is a `__init__` importing 
`from opcua.client.client import Client` from a folder client that exists on the same level as `__init__`. that folder has a module client.py and that module is holding class "Client". so to me everything appears fine but I am not very experienced here.

Not sure what is causing this? thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above issue did take me quite some time and after being stuck for one evening I decided to ask. However, I eductated myself on packages that morning and appears like sys.path(0..) is the reason. Not 100% sure why it is used but it somehow changes directory. After puting file into my Python directory /Pyton35-32 it is working

Comment: why dont you install free opcua. Then you dont need to include sys. Directly import it

Comment: which file did u put in python directory /Python35-32. I am facing same issue ."ImportError: cannot import name 'Client'"